# MVC3: Attribute for not mapping a property to a DB column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m using ASP.NET MVC3. I have a model that has one property that I don’t want to store in the database. Is there an attribute that I can put on the property to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What ORM are you using? How are you using it?

Comment: I'm using EF 4.0. I'm not doing anything special with it except for adding some validation attributes on my model class. I'm letting EF create the database for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute are in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: In MVC5 / EF6, the namespace is `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more options... this is why I prefer to keep my domain model separate from my view model. My view model often has additional fields necessary for rendering the view which does not belong in the domain model. The design I typically use is described pretty well [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/).